# How to delete Images on Android 8.1.0?

Tags: storage, images

Android is complaining of dwindling storage space. I regularly delete personal files to comply with its demands and can now use but 20 Gb of a 32 Gb storage unit. Recently I noticed an item called **Images** in the *Storage* -> *Photos & videos* dialogue:

[image]

The trash bin of the Photos application is empty, and so far I could not identify these "images" in the system. How can I delete them?

**Update**: I have wiped the system cache, follow the procedure described here. This had no effect, the phone still reports 3 GB of images that are nowhere to be found.

Comment: I am on Oreo 8.0 which has different options. Wondering if it is images that are pending deletion in [smart storage](https://tunecomp.net/smart-storage-feature-in-android-8-oreo-free-up-space-automatically/) . If you enabled it , disable it and see if you can still see *images* eat space

Comment: I have smart storage disabled. I have never enabled it.

Answer (score -1):

These are the caches Images which Android stores it in itself. To delete these Images, go to your File browser and allow the File browser to show Hidden Files and then Go to

Phone Storage > DCIM > .thumbnails

There are image more than 100 image and some waste files stored under this folder. Delete whole folder. Doing this can help you in some Manner to get out of dwindling storage.

Comment: There were about 140 MB in that folder. Very far from the 3 GB reported by the system.

Comment: Go and check images in your gallery that they worth 3 gb or not. If not then check each and every folder of yiur internal storage and delete each image which is waste for you.